# How to reverse a string using loops in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring, string-length

So I created this code and i was wondering how I would be able to loop depending on the amount of spaces there are in the userInput.

```js
    var userInput = prompt("Enter a phrase you want to reverse?")
    var userOutput = ""
    var array = []
    var length = userInput.length;
    var str = userInput.lastIndexOf(" ")
    var test = userInput.substr(str, length);
```

The main Objective of this program is to reverse the userInput by not using js methods
Input:
"Hello world"
Output:
world Hello

Comment: Well if you have an idea of which JS methods to use, you could think about how you could implement these. Divide and conquer.

Comment: By not using JS methods, do you mean just things like `split`, `reverse`, `join` etc.

Comment: "by not using js methods" Not possible using properties only. Please elaborate your question, what exactly are the methods you don't want to use?

Comment: methods not to use: reverse(), trim(), join(), split()

Comment: Just so I'm clear, what do you want the output to be on the input "I am the walrus"?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, pure reversing can be done using properties only. But how are the spaces involved? You want to reverse words in a string only, not the whole string?

Answer (score 0):

1) `Split` the string on `' '`, save to an array of strings

2) Reverse the array

3) `Join` the array elements with `' '`

Comment: due to the limitation I am unable to use these methods

Comment: In which case, write your own methods that perform the built-in operations.  Its still the same procedure.  `reverse` will be easy, as will `join`.  `split` will be tougher but not too challenging, although you will likely end up with a less efficient function that the built-in.  That said, I don't see what the point is: you're reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userInput = prompt("Enter a phrase you want to reverse?")
var userOutput = ""
var array = []
var length = userInput.length;
var str = userInput.lastIndexOf(" ")
var test = userInput.substr(str, length);
var reversed = "";

while (length) {
     reversed += test[--length];
}
```

Edit:
Woha! I should have been more careful using test.length instead of input length.
I will leave it for you as an practice to find and fix the bug I made.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot.

Comment: If it helped then no problem. Just have fun.

Comment: If you haven't tried already, you should also play with *pre* (--var) and *post* (var--) *decrement*ation. Every play will make the concepts more concrete. You then just google what the difference is.